# How to Handle Flutter Web View Click in IOS

Tags: flutter, webview, instagram

I am using webview_flutter plugin for instagram login.Its working fine in Android and return me access token. But in IOS "onPageFinished" is not getting called on "Save Info" or "Not now" click. So i am not able to get access token in case of IOS.I  am attaching the code screenshot.Please check it and help me out.[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add this line in Info.plist

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<string>YES</string></dict>
```